# Seriously confused: has ActiveMQ dropped support for connection pooling?

Tags: activemq-classic, apollo

I'm new to ActiveMQ (we use Apollo for the broker). Everything I read says to use org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory for connection pool, except that class does not exist in activemq-all-5.5.0.jar. According to jarfinder.com that class only exists in older versions of ActiveMQ.

Do I have to include Spring or something? How does one pool connections?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In a standard ActiveMQ distribution you have lib/optional/activemq-pool-5.8.0.jar which contains this class.

Not sure for apollo, but I guess you use the ActiveMQ JMS library for that anyway?

Comment: And there it is, thanks. activemq-all-5.5.0.jar might be better named activemq-almost-all-5.5.0.jar

Comment: note the name "optional" in the folder name. But yes, activemq-all is perhaps a bit misleading in that sense

Answer (score 0):

For maven users, this helps:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
        <version>${activemq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```